# 'ImageButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

Tags: asp.net

**I've got the ImageButton wrapped inside a form tag with runat="server"** but STILL getting this error at runtime.  The form tag is at the very beginning (before my table) and end tag is at the end (after the table).

```
<td>
    <div>
    <div id="pay-Button"><asp:ImageButton ID="PayButton" ImageUrl="<%=PayButtonImageUrl %>" OnClick="RedirectTest" runat="server" /></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Interesting, when I move that ImageButton out of the <div> all is fine.  But that does not make my happy.  I need it inside the div.

Comment: The only thing I can think of here is that there is another form tag inside my main form tag that does not have a runat="server".  And that form tag without the runat="server" is right above my ImageButton.  If I move out my ImageButton to right above that inner form tag then it's fine.  Would that inner form tag without a runat="server" cause problems?  Would be very weird if my control isn't even inside that inner form tag...makes no sense that this would cause a problem.

Comment: What is the purpose of having nested forms on the page?

Comment: well, the inner form tag without runat="server" was not the problem either.  It's weird that if I move up my ImageButton to a certain point within the <td> that it works.  I've got nothing special wrapping it.

Comment: hmm, it's definitely that inner form tag.  If I move my asp.net control above that form tag it is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have managed controls within a `<form>` tag without the `runat='server'`.  ASP.Net supports multiple form tags, but with only one of them having a server-side designation.  Also, I don't believe that HTML supports nested forms.  You'll either want to have it be a non-managed control in a separate form or remove the nested `<form>` tag from the server-side form.

Look [here for further explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164151.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

remove the `ImageUrl="<%=PayButtonImageUrl %>"` part, I don't believe you can use those inline snippits for server control properties (unless you're databinding)

Comment: Well then how can I get my code-behind property to set that but doing that in mark-up (not setting it from code-behind)?

Comment: <%# %> is for databainding I believe, not <%= %>

Comment: Made no difference removing that anyway...still the same problem.

Comment: well that wasn't the problem, but you'll still have to end up setting it in the code behind.  Once you get your code working (which we can't determine the cause from the limited code you have here; it looks valid), and you still have the <%= %> code in there, the generated page will literally have "src='<%=PayButtonImageUrl %>'" as it's value for the image

Answer (score -1):

Does your  tag also have

```
runat="server"
```

as an attribute?

It would be helpful if you showed more of your code so we can help.

Comment: I explained to you that the form tag has runat=server and wraps the entire table that this section of code is in.